# Merge the same Access database frequently (daily/weekly)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sharepoint

I need to use one Access(2007)database on 2 offline locations and then get all the data back in one database. Some advised me to use SharePoint, but after some trial and frustration I wonder if it's really the best way. 
Is it possible to manage this in an automated way, with update queries or so?

I have 26 tables, but only 14 need to be updated frequently. I use autonumber to create the parentkey and use cascade updating for the linked tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data can handle it, it's probably better to use a more natural key for the tables that require frequent updating. I.e. ideally you can uniquely identify a record my some combination of the columns in that record. Autonumbers in two databases can, and very likely will, step on each other, then when you do merge any records based on an old auto number need to be mapped properly. That can be done but is kind of a pain. It'd be nicer to avoid it all from the start.

As for using Sharepoint (I assume the suggestion is to replace your tables with lists, not to just put your accdb on SP) it has a lot of limitations in terms of the kinds of indices that can be created and relationships you can establish. Maybe your data are simple enough to live with this. I'm yet to be able to justify the move.

ultimate the answer to your question is **YES** it is possible to manage the synchonization with insert/update queries and very likely some VBA (possibly lots depending on how complicated your table hierarchy is). You'll need to be vigilant about two people updating a single record. You'll need to come up with some means to resolve the conflict.

Comment: I was already thinking about natural keys, good point. 
Which conflicts would come up? Non existing key & data is quite easy to add with an insert query I assume.

Comment: I'm not sure what data your storing but even with natural keys a conflict can a rise. The advantage is it is very obvious where that conflict is. It's likely you'd want to deal with them manually. Something automated to deal with conflicts sounds like a recipe for disaster. As for inserting new records, again, you want to be very careful. You don't want to insert new domain values automatically without first looking at them (Spaces, spelling differences). Automatically inserting new data records I would assume is a valid thing to do. After all that's probably the whole purpose.

Comment: I think that I'll rename the database (tablet1, tablet2) if it goes to a certain tablet and than automatically (VBA) add this name to the natural key, so there shouldn't be a conflict once it is synced back to the masterDB.
The domain values are created automatically or by lookup lists, so that shouldn't give any problem.